# Space separated argument to script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use a wrapper bash script to execute some command with one parameter separated by space 'A B'.

foo-wrapper.sh content:

```
#/!bin/bash
foo $1
```

When running foo-wrapper.sh:

```
$bash -x foo-wrapper.sh "'A B'"
+ Error: foo ''\''A' 'B'\'''
```

The expected call would be: `foo 'A B'`

Any ideas how to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the wrapper replace `$1` by `"$1"`.
  If your arguments/variables contain space characters, you need to quote them to prevent them from being split.
- In the call instead of `"'A B'"` use one of `"A B"`, `'A B'` or `A\ B`.
  These are the most usual ways of specifying strings in BASH. (Note that the whitespace only makes a difference in the 3rd case. You would have to use quotes in the first two cases no matter whether you have a space or not.)

If you want to play around a little to get a feeling, you can start with:

```
$ foo() { echo "count: $#"; echo "arg 1: $1"; echo "arg 2: $2"; }
$ foo A\ B C
count: 2
arg 1: A B
arg 2: C
```